Resubscribe to a Sink after termination
I have a sink that has a subscriber further down the line. During stress testing we realized that the queue was been filled up and the sink emitted a FAIL_OVERFLOW signal. After continuing the test all emitNext calls started throwing the signal FAIL_TERMINATED.
My first thought was to put a retry() or onErrorContinue() or something like that but the problem is not the subscription is cancelled but the sink is KO.
Is there a way to know the status of a sink before emitting and/or a graceful way of reestablish/resubscribe to a terminated sink?
This is an example of my code
class class EventEmitter {

   public void emitNext(Event event){
       log(event);
       unhandledEvents.emitNext(event, emitNextFailureHandler);
   }

   public Flux<Event> getEvents() {
      return unhandledEvents.asFlux();
   }
 
   private final Sinks.Many<Event> unhandledEvents = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
}

public class otherClass {

   public void function(){
      eventEmitter.getEvents()
            .filter(this::shouldKeepGoing)
            .doOnNext(repository::remove)
            .subscribe();
  }
}

Using reactor 3.4

Hi, is unhandledEvents and deniedTimeoutEvents the same variable or not? Is PriceEvent and Event the same class or not? Also there're several unknown functions & variables make this example hard to reproduce.

Yes to both questions, sorry, I was going back and forth between my example and the real code and mix them accidentally.

Is the implementation of EventEmitter under your control? or it is just a mock implementation of external service? If they're under your control I think you can make the emitNextFailureHandler returns true when encountering FAIL_OVERFLOW or FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED so that the EventEmitter can retry emit.
Simple example:
Sinks.EmitFailureHandler emitNextFailureHandler = (signalType, emitResult) -> {
    return Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_OVERFLOW.equals(emitResult) || Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED.equals(emitResult);
};

However, in practice you may need to add max retry limit or retry interval to avoid potential infinite retry.

Also, I'd like to discuss this in another aspect.
I think the repository::remove is a synchronized method that blocks the same thread so that's why the queue is under pressure so hard. This might not be a best practice for reactive programming. A better way to do this might be to make the repository.remove() return a Mono or Flux (in practice you may need to change the dependencies to Reactive related dependencies e.g. Spring Data R2DBC), then use .flatMap(repository::remove) instead of .doOnNext()
